# What do the double parenthesis mean?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, casting

Looking at the Apple sample code for `iPhoneCoreDataRecipes`, I have a question about the snippet below from the `RecipeDetailViewController.m`:

```
case TYPE_SECTION:
    nextViewController = [[TypeSelectionViewController alloc]
        initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    ((TypeSelectionViewController *)nextViewController).recipe = recipe;
    break;
```

In the line `((TypeSelectionViewController *)nextViewController).recipe = recipe`, I understand that the inner parenthesis are to typecast the view controller as a `TypeSelectionViewController`, but what do the outer parenthesis do?

Comment: Operator precedence.  You want to look at `.recipe` of `nextViewController` as a `(TypeSelectionViewController *)`.  You don't want to cast `nextViewController.recipe` as a `(TypeSelectionViewController *)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's to do with the precedence of operations.

If you look [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_2.0_Operator_Precedence) , you can see that dot notation has a higher precedence than casting.

So this code:

```
(TypeSelectionViewController *)nextViewController.recipe
```

would be converted by the compiler to the following (since dot . notation is just syntactic sugar for the compiler):

```
(TypeSelectionViewController *)[nextViewController recipe]
```

However, we wanted to cast the `nextViewController` part to type `TypeSelectionViewController *`, and not the `[nextViewController recipe]` part. So this is incorrect.

So instead we write this:

```
((TypeSelectionViewController *)nextViewController).recipe
```

which the compiler converts to this:

```
[(TypeSelectionViewController *)nextViewController recipe]
```

which is what we want.

**Note on compiler versus runtime behaviour**

If you compile this example of incorrect casting:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
NSString *result = (UILabel *)label.text;
```

You will get a message like this from the compiler:

```
Warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSString *' with an 
  expression of type 'UILabel *'
```

**However, the code will work fine at runtime due to Objective C's weak typing.** You can read more about this at the [LLVM docs](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html), e.g.:

> The validity of conversions between object pointer types is not
>   checked at runtime.

Comment: And it never hurts to have extra parens, if you're unsure of the precedence rules.  They don't cost anything.

Answer (score 0):

It's a cast, it's say to consider nextViewController is an instance of TypeSelectionViewController so you can use it's property recipe

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question already states that he understand the cast. The question is about the outer parentheses.